# Handling caching in asp.net environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am researching on how to handle caching in .net environment. I know that .NET supports the caching class object and we can always use it but here the problem that I am facing is different.

When we talk about caching(data caching), we are actually caching all the information from the DB but at the same time we want to make sure that we want to use the cached values ONLY IF the database has not changed. Otherwise we want to be reading those values from the database.

IS there any framework that I can use? Does it support in a webfarm environment?

Comment: What database product are you using? How did you implement your data access layer?

Answer (score 6):

Read this:

Caching in ASP.NET with the SqlCacheDependency Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx

and

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-sql-cache-dependencies-vb

Comment: Well, the problem here is that we are not using SQL Server for out database so the solution has to be completely independent from SQl and native C#